# Uploading file via FTP when VPN

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have a straightforward program that uploads a file to a FTP server.
This works when I'm not on a VPN (Hotspot Shield).

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.connect(ftpServer);
ftp.login(log,pw);
ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(dir);

File f = new File(FileName);
final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f.getPath());
ftp.storeFile(f.getName(), is);

ftp.disconnect();
is.close();
```

However, when I am connected to a VPN, it runs with no errors and doesn't throw any exceptions, but the file just doesn't get uploaded.

I've tried to FTP via command window,
and when I try to `mput` it gives me this error:

> "I won't open a connection to 'random ip address' (ony to 'another
>   random ip')

So now I think this is some kind of FTP restriction problem with VPN?

Anybody have any kind of experience with this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I found a solution,
calling `ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();` before I storeFile() seems to have resolve the error.

Comment: I assume the `ftp.storeFile()` returns `false`, right? What does `ftp.getReply()` return after the `storeFile` fails?

Comment: `ftp.storefile()` does return false, `ftp.getReply()` seems to just hang.

I found this:
http://superuser.com/questions/627733/fireftp-with-hotspot-shield

And now I'm even more convince that it has something to do with HotSpot Shield not supporting FTP.

Comment: I've meant `getReplyStrings()`, not `getReply()`, sorry.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, calling `ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();` before I `storeFile()` seems to have resolve the error.